# Create dynamic tiles - windows 8.1 using c# and xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

[image: sample gridview]

I am new to windows store 8.1 development using xaml and c#. I will like to create a xaml page below with dynamic data. Does anyone have a link or direction on how I can do this?

Comment: There's multiple ways of doing this with existing controls, especially if you just set a wrap panel or something as the item panel on something like itemscontrol, gridview, semantic zoom, listbox, with a quick custom template etc. So my question in response would probably be, what have you tried? You might start by looking at the docs for just the [controls available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351.aspx) to you.

Comment: I tried the gridview but was not able to get the square shape. I was able to return data very well.

Comment: Maybe show what you tried or a screenshot of the result or something to help us help you.